# Java : Array items null and int values

Tags: java, arrays, oop, null, int

I have an array with type Object. Then I assign it's values to null. But later I want to assign int values on null cells. Is that possible?
In these lines:

```
    Queue[y]=new Int;
    Queue[y]=num;
```

I am trying create an object Int type, in the null cell. But I get this error:

```
error: '(' or '[' expected
            Queue[y]=new Int;
```

---

```
private Object Queue[];
public PriorityQueue(int capacity){
     this.capacity=capacity;
     Queue= new Object [capacity];
     for(int i=0;i<=Queue.length;i++) {
            Queue[i]=null;
     }
}

public boolean insert(int num){
     if (y<capacity){
            Queue[y]=new Int;
            Queue[y]=num;
            y++;
            return true;
     }
     else{
            y++;
            return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: You always need a parameter list when you invoke a constructor, even if it is empty: `new Int()`. Or, if you mean to create an array, you need to specify the number of elements: `new Int[10]`.

Comment: It's `Integer`, not `Int`, and it requires a value for the constructor, so `new Integer(5)`. But you don't need that line at all since you're assigning `num` to that spot in the array in the very next line.

Comment: @GriffeyDog how do you know it's not a custom class called `Int`? It's a valid class name.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just assuming...

Comment: "I want to assign int values on null cells. Is that possible?" No. You can assign `Integer` values, but not `int` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I don't know what class you mean by `Int` - perhaps you mean `java.lang.Integer`, but perhaps you mean some custom class. It's not totally relevant to the answer, however)*

You always need a parameter list when you invoke a constructor, even if it is empty:

```
new Int()
```

Or, if you mean to create an array, you need to specify the number of elements:

```
new Int[10]
```

However, you don't need the first assignment:

```
Queue[y]=new Int();
Queue[y]=num;
```

The second line overwrites the value in the first line, so it's actually just creating an object and then immediately discarding it.

You could simply write:

```
Queue[y]=num;
```

Note that this isn't actually assigning an `int` to an `Object` array element: due to *autoboxing*, the compiler automatically converts this to:

```
Queue[y]=Integer.valueOf(num);
```

so an instance of `Integer` is being added to the array. However, this conversion isn't something that you need to do yourself.